# Is there any way to make Aptana studio select every instance of a selected word?

Tags: aptana

Is Aptana studio able to do this: if I select a word in my code, can Aptana automatically select this word everywhere in the code?

For example: if I select "mercedes", Aptana automatically selects every instance of "mercedes" in this code.